# Apache2 HTTP Ubuntu Won't Restart

Tags: apache2, webserver, ssl

Hey since I have attempted to install SSL onto my site I am unable to restart without removing it from the config.

I am running Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04 x64

Changes for SSL:

```
DocumentRoot   /var/www/html
ServerName     my_site_name.com -- I have the actual site name here
SSLEngine      on
SSLCertificateFile        /ssl-files/site_name.com.crt # I have the actual cert here
SSLCertificateKeyFile     /ssl-files/site_name.key # I have the actual key name here
```

However when I run this I in the conf I get

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with this error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

For some reason when I remove the SSL parts it works fine, I have tried purging and reinstalling apache2, with no luck.

apache2.server Log:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-09-29 13:08:42 UTC; 1min 41s ago
  Process: 19553 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 19563 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18805 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Sep 29 13:08:42 nickr.0103 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 29 13:08:42 nickr.0103 apachectl[19563]: Action 'start' failed.
Sep 29 13:08:42 nickr.0103 apachectl[19563]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Sep 29 13:08:42 nickr.0103 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 29 13:08:42 nickr.0103 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 29 13:08:42 nickr.0103 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I have read this error before so I changed my key and crt, however it still gives me this error.

```
[Sat Sep 29 14:16:39.277651 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 20797] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate www.my_site.com:443:0 (with chain), check /ssl-files/my_site.crt
[Sat Sep 29 14:16:39.277794 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 20797] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
[Sat Sep 29 14:16:39.277820 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 20797] SSL Library Error: error:140DC009:SSL routines:use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: Please run `systemctl status apache2.service` and [edit] your post to include this information.

Comment: What does the Apache log files show? They are typically located in `/var/log/apache2/`

Comment: There you go, added the error.log

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [Sat Sep 29 14:16:39.277794 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 20797] SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?
> ```

This line is the actual error. The Certificate is not in correct format, or corrupt.

Verify that the certificates are readable with `openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in certificate.crt` to verify the certificate. It should output modulus of the certificate.

To verify key, use `openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in keyfile.key`.

The modulus of the certificate and key file should additionally be identical. Otherwise they do not match.

If openssl fails, get new certificate files from your provider.

Comment: They are identical and I think there is an error with them, I have even gotten new ones but still get that error, this is what I get from them. `unable to load certificate
139816630936000:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:691:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
`